# Allow urls containing "www." on openshift hosted website

Tags: python, flask, openshift

I have a (very) simple flask app hosted on open-shift.

It has one route:

```
@app.route('/')
def display_content():
    return render_template("content.html.jnj2")
```

and a simple wsgi file (as described in the open-shift flask setup tutorial):

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

httpd = make_server('localhost', 8051, application)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This works fine when I navigate to "myappname-mydomain.rhcloud.com", but gives an "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" when I navigate to "www.myappname-mydomain.rhcloud.com".

I've done some googling etc, can't see anyone else with a similar problem.. I'm not aware of having changed any open-shift settings or anything.

Comment: Also I tried naively aliasing (via the open-shift website) www.myappname-mydomain.rhcloud.com to myappname-mydomain.rhcloud.com, but that gives a "The specified alias is not allowed: ... " error

Comment: This has nothing to do with flask or python. You can modify your dns settings on your nameserver to send www.example.com and example.com to the same IP address. Or you could put a wildcard setting in your DNS and tell your webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc..) what to do about redirecting one to the other.

Comment: As I said, this is an app hosted on open-shift. Your comment misses the point - see the answer below

Comment: And if what I've done doesn't give the result I expect, including the relevant code and context is not unreasonable

Comment: (although yes I shouldn't have included the suggested 'python' tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app-domain.rhcloud.com address that is provided by OpenShift does NOT include a cname for www.app-domain.rhcloud.com, that's why it's not working.  You can use your app-domain.rhcloud.com, or you can map your own alias like example.com or www.example.com using this guide: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-domains-ssl.html#using-a-custom-domain

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but going by eg [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23307678/3832080) I thought it unlikely